# ConcurrentHashMap crashing application compiled with JDK 8 but targeting JRE 7

Tags: java, iteration, concurrenthashmap

I ran into a very unexpected error today and while I was able to find a way to fix the problem as a whole I'm not sure I completely understand why it did what it did.

The code I'm working with was originally written with a JDK 7 environment of course targeting JRE 7. In the code I was using a `ConcurrentHashMap` and needed to iterate over the keys in the map. For this I was using the `map.keySet()` which according to the JavaDocs should return a `Set<K>`. This worked fine until our build environment switched to JDK8.

When we moved to JDK8 I ensured that I was calling a target/source for 1.7 when calling the javac. So I was pretty surprised when the code started failing right when it wanted to iterate through the keys of the map. No error was thrown, no exception, the thread just simply stopped. After doing some research I found that Java8's implementation for `ConcurrentHashMap` the `.keySet()` method returns a `KeySetView<K,V>`.

I fixed the problem by switching from using the `map.keySet()` to getting an `Enumeration<K>` using `map.keys()`.

Now my guess as to the problem is that although the project was compiled targeting Java7 since the JDK8 was used the Java8 libraries were included, but why didn't it thrown an error or an exception when it hit the mismatch?

As asked here is a code snippet:

```
class MapProcessing
{
     private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();

     public MapProcessing()
     {
           map.put("First",new Object());
           map.put("Second",new Object());
           map.put("Third",new Object());
     } 


     public void processing()
     {
          // when calling this type of loop causes a freeze on our system.
          for(String key : map.keySet())
          {
              System.out.println(key);
          }
      }

     public void working()
     {
         // This is what I had to do to fix the problem.
         Enumeration<String> keys = map.keys();
         while(keys.hasMoreElements())
         {
              String key = keys.nextElement();
              System.out.println(key);
         }
     }
}
```

We are compiling using Oracle JDK 8 build 40 using a target for 1.7 and source 1.7 in the javac on a Windows 2012 server.

The code is running using Oracle JVM 7 build 25 running on Windows 2012 server.

Comment: Did you try cleaning it after attaching JDK 8 ?

Comment: @suresh the build environment is a Jenkins. When we moved to JDK8 we deleted the workspace and then performed a new build. This would mean the code was freshly checked out of SVN and then built. I'm not sure what you mean by cleaning it other than the standard call to a "clean" target in ant, which happens.

Comment: can you post a code snippet and the exact JVM version and vendor + OS? KeySetView<K,V> implements Set<K> so this at least should not be really an issue

Comment: @salyh provided as asked.

Comment: I've added the work around that I used to fix the problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If i compile your code with Java 8 and javac -source 1.7 -target 1.8 and then run it with Java 7 i get an

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView;
    at stackoverflowt.Test.processing(Test.java:20)
    at stackoverflowt.Test.main(Test.java:27)
```

This is because the the byte code looks like

```
public void processing();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: getfield      #4                  // Field map:Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap;
       4: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.keySet:()Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView;
       7: invokevirtual #11                 // Method java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
      10: astore_1
```

and referring explicitly to ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView which is not present in Java 7. I am on Mac with Java 1.7.0_79 and 1.8.0_45

If you change the code to (only use the Map Interface):

```
private Map<String, Object> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
```

then it work's for me. Bytecode then looks like

```
public void processing();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: getfield      #4                  // Field map:Ljava/util/Map;
       4: invokeinterface #10,  1           // InterfaceMethod java/util/Map.keySet:()Ljava/util/Set;
       9: invokeinterface #11,  1           // InterfaceMethod java/util/Set.iterator:()Ljava/util/Iterator;
      14: astore_1
```

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't thought about using the generic Map interface. Sadly, I never saw a `NoSuchMethodError`. I would have expected at least that. I'll have to look into the cod again tomorrow to see if the error handling is actually catching everything correctly. Thanks.

Comment: I checked my code this morning and sure enough the call that kicks everything off is wrapped in a try catch but only catching exceptions and `NoSuchMethodError` is `Throwable` but not an `Exception`. This gives me a better understanding as to why I didn't see an error when the program broke.

Comment: @JRSofty If it's a problem that Java can't recover from it, it'll be an [`Error`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html), which is a subclass of `Throwable` but not `Exception`.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you build a project using a newer JDK using the `-source` argument targeting an older version, you'll get this compiler warning:

`warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7`

[This blog entry](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/bootclasspath_older_source) talks about what it means.

Basically, you get this warning because Java is compiling it using older language rules but against the newer class library... and there are some compatibility issues with the Java 8 versions as Oracle moved some of the internal classes around.

The fix is to use the `-bootclasspath` argument to point it at the `rt.jar` from the older version while compiling.

Comment: Ok, so adding pointing to the correct rt.jar using the `-bootclasspath` option should make work as expected. Although I guess my fix is probably better as it means when we deploy the application on a system running JRE 8 then I don't have to worry about it breaking. What I'm curious about though is why did I not get an exception or error when I ran the program? For me the thread just stopped and no exception was thrown.

Comment: Thanks again for the information on the build environment. I will be fixing this as soon as possible. We never added the `bootclasspath` option to the `javac` ant task. I'll be doing that immediately.