# ProcessSimulator.killAllProcesses(line:78) NoSuchMethodError ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-storm

Why?
I am using Storm for the first time (learning from getting started with storm) and run success but found NoSuchMethodError:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView;
        at org.apache.storm.ProcessSimulator.killAllProcesses(ProcessSimulator.java:78) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.testing$kill_local_storm_cluster.invoke(testing.clj:206) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.LocalCluster$_shutdown.invoke(LocalCluster.clj:66) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.LocalCluster.shutdown(Unknown Source) ~[storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at com.wjl.hello.TopologyMain.main(TopologyMain.java:45) ~[storm-hello-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
```

and

```
org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x15b28de9a8b0011, likely client has closed socket
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) [storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) [storm-core-1.0.3.jar:1.0.3]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [?:1.7.0_15]
```

Running successfully:

```
-- Word Counter [word-counter-2] --
yes: 1 is: 5 it: 1 what: 1 apple: 1 name: 4 your: 3 funny: 1 haha: 2 en: 1 my: 2 this: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

That may be Java 8 <> 7 incompatibility issue. Please. check this question: [ConcurrentHashMap crashing application compiled with JDK 8 but targeting JRE 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954041/concurrenthashmap-crashing-application-compiled-with-jdk-8-but-targeting-jre-7/32955708#32955708)